# Wordpress <html>-Tag hook/filter?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, application-cache

Im writing a application cache plugin for Wordpress.
I was wondering how i can modify the <\html> tag in the **current theme** from my plugin to:

<\html manifest="Site_url().../plugin/bla.php?var1=foo&var2=bar">

I was googling and looking up stuff on the wordpress' dev site, but no luck yet.

I appreciate any help (:

Best,
m

Comment: Your plugin has a tag you want to modify?  Or you want your plugin to modify the closing html tag?

Comment: i want my plugin to modify the <*html*> tag in the /theme/blatheme/header.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `language_attributes`.  This assumes that they have followed wordpress theme standards and their header includes the following:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<html id="ie6" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html id="ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html id="ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 6) | !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Example of the filter:

```
function jrod_add_html_manifest( $output ) {

    $output .= ' manfiest="Site_url().../plugin/bla.php?var1=foo&var2=bar"';

    return $output;
}

add_filter( 'language_attributes', 'jrod_add_html_manifest' );
```

Comment: thank you! This will only help if the user has the  language_attributes() function in the header(which has not that widely supported). I absolutely need a fallback - i think im doing it with javascript (with the wp_head hook which is more widely supported). Do you have any other ideas for a fallback?

Comment: You can always inform users that the `language_attributes()` is required in the html tag.